# Check nil on multiple variables

Tags: ruby, null

A lot of variables require some processing, so I'm checking if any of them are `nil`. Is there a more efficient way of writing the following?

```
unless a.nil? || b.nil? || c.nil? || d.nil? || e.nil? || f.nil? || g.nil?
  render 'view'
end
```

Or should I avoid checking a lot of variables for `nil` on one line?

Comment: is `false` valid or is it the same as `nil`? because if `false` is the same as `nil`, I would simply drop the `.nil?` method call (which degrades performance anyway). Even if other code reads better, I doubt anything would perform better then @Meier 's answer... (except, **maybe** dropping the `if`, so we get `a && b && c && d && e && f && render('view')`)

Comment: @Myst, sorry I forgot to mention that some of the variables are arrays that cannot be empty, so taking from @zetetic 's answer, would `if [a,b,c,d,e,f,g].none{ |x| x.nil? || x.empty? }` be a good solution?

Comment: In Rails you also get the `blank?` method, which can be called on instances of NilClass, String and Array. So `.none(&:blank?)` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you should write a question with more details regarding your needs or what problem you're actually trying to solve. What about Arrays with `nil` of `false` (i.e. `[1, nil]` or `[false, nil]`)? What about empty Hashes or hashes of `nil`? What about empty strings? what about strings with only white spaces (spaces, new lines etc')? what of `false` or `nil`?    ....   P.S. I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve, but I suspect a different design might help you avoid this huge `if` statement.

Comment: @Myst, zetetic's comment above is what I'm looking for. Your additional questions don't apply in my case. I'll try to add more specifics next time though, thanks.

Comment: I'm happy you found what you're looking for. Be aware that `blank?` will return `true` for white-space strings (`" \n\t".blank? == true`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using `none?` you can have `if` instead of `unless`:

```
if [a,b,c,d,e,f,g].none?(&:nil?)
```

Come to think of it, this can be reduced to simply:

```
if [a,b,c,d,e,f,g].all?
```

if you don't mind treating `false` the same as `nil`

> Is there a more efficient way of writing the following?

I think a better question is, "Is there a more *expressive* way of writing..."

Answer (score 8):

```
unless [a,b,c,d,e,f,g].include?(nil)
  render 'view'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
render 'view' unless [a,b,c,d,e,f,g].any?(&:nil?)
```

Another way:

```
render 'view' if [a,b,c,d,e,f,g].index(nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also some other method:

```
arr = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
render 'view' if arr.compact == arr
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `a,b,c...` are objects (or something that is never `false`) you can write it like this:

```
if a && b && c && d && e && f
    render 'view' 
end
```